# need help to fix the link in my javascript code

Tags: javascript, youtube

can some one help me to fix this link in my javascript code

the code is

```
$('.frame_src').attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + $(this).data('str'));
```

full link is https://www.youtube.com/embed/p9zdCra9gCE?&vq=hd720&rel=0;autoplay=1

i want to make it something like this i know it's wrong but i can't fix it

```
$('.frame_src').attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' '?&vq=hd720&rel=0;autoplay=1' + $(this).data('str'));
```

Comment: sorry i meant javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, you need to insert the `$(this).data('str')` value in the right place.

Change

`$('.frame_src').attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' '?&vq=hd720&rel=0;autoplay=1' + $(this).data('str'));`

to

`$('.frame_src').attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + $(this).data('str') + '?&vq=hd720&rel=0;autoplay=1');`

Comment: can you please check and answer this question if you can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945525/hide-div-and-show-iframe-with-countdown-using-javascript