# hide div and show iframe with countdown using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

When the page load this iframe `class="frame_src"` must be hidden like, `display="none"`

And after 10 seconds this div must hide `class="load_video"` and show `iframe class="frame_src"`

Right now the problem is when countdown is counting somehow the iframe video plays in background, I can hear it, and when the 10 seconds elapsed, it will play the video again.

Here's my full code : http://plnkr.co/edit/LhxRjJXBnCGKGfW4ZLWO?p=preview

Here's my javascript code :

```
<script>
function startChecking() {
    secondsleft -= 1e3, document.querySelector(".load_video").innerHTML = "Please Wait.. " + Math.abs(secondsleft / 1e3) + " Seconds", 0 == secondsleft && (clearInterval(interval), $(".reloadframe").show(), document.querySelector(".load_video").style.display = "none", document.querySelector(".frame_src").style.display = "", document.querySelector(".frame_src").src = document.querySelector(".frame_src").getAttribute("data-src"))
}

function startschedule() {
    clearInterval(interval), secondsleft = threshold, document.querySelector(".load_video").innerHTML = "Please Wait.. " + Math.abs(secondsleft / 1e3) + " Seconds", interval = setInterval(function () {
        startChecking()
    }, 1e3)
}

function resetTimer() {
    startschedule()
}
var timeout, interval, threshold = 1e4,
    secondsleft = threshold;
window.onload = function () {
    startschedule()
};
</script>
```

Comment: Your fiddle code on plunker is not clear and has many syntax errors(php codes inside it and so). Please create a clear and working fiddle and update you post again so we can trace the code and find the error.

Comment: dear, there is no error all codes are working fine on my website. what i need is, when i navigate to the page, that iframe i mentioned it must be hidden and when countdown hits 0 then hide class="load_video" and show iframe. i am sure  it can be done from that code that is in header as you see on plnkr. but i don't know how to do it. i don't have much experience in javascript. it works hidding div and showing iframe but the problem is while countdown is counting the video will play. so it doesn't hide iframe properly in beginning. hope you understand

Comment: I know, you got me wrong. I mean the link which you have provided in this post on plunker website has errors in it and therefor the page is not working properly. So I'm asking you to create a simple page with just what is necessary for your question and then create another plukner url so we can debug your code. this link  http://plnkr.co/edit/LhxRjJXBnCGKGfW4ZLWO?p=preview does not show any videos and the iframe in it is visible from the beginning.

Comment: i know but developer made that code for me and he said i have to run it on server that supports php. if you have a server make a simple page and upload it you ill see it like it should be. it is not showing it well on plnkr

Comment: I'm sorry, I have a server, but it's not my responsibility to upload this file on my server, it's your responsibility to create a clean and simple working fiddle if you really want people on SO to help you. we are here to help you to solve your problem, not to clean your code and make if functional to identify the problem afterward! If you ever manage to create a clean fiddle, then please update your post and add it here so we can trace your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96299/discussion-between-ehsant-and-user099023).

Comment: I think I found the solution for you, It's somehow related to `iframe` and `caching` it's contents. It's actually a workaround. you have to clear the content of the `iframe` every time page loads.

Comment: i want to have a chat with you ehsan to discuss something about this

Comment: Sure, right now I'm away from computer. If you don't mind can we have the chat for tomorrow?

Comment: dear, when you have time please send me chat request i need a little help on my code

Comment: hi my friend. hope you ding good. when you are free please send me chat request i need very small code if you can make it for me. thanks

Comment: send me chat request when you free my friend

Comment: please send me chat request my friend when ever you free

Comment: sorry you sent me chat request i wasn't here. please send it again when you free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you have to clear the content of the `iframe` as well as it's `src`.

You can use `about:blank` for it's `src` as it loads a bland page in the `iframe`

so if you add

```
document.querySelector(".frame_src").src = "about:blank";
```

to the beginning of the `startschedule()` function, it will do the trick for you.

your function should look like this after the change:

```
function startschedule() {
    document.querySelector(".frame_src").src = "about:blank";
    clearInterval(interval), secondsleft = threshold, document.querySelector(".load_video").innerHTML = "Please Wait.. " + Math.abs(secondsleft / 1e3) + " Seconds", interval = setInterval(function() {
        startChecking()
    }, 1e3)
}
```